# Can two NSPersistentStoreCoordinator use the same DB?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am considering to use two `persistent store coordinator`, `PSC1` would **only read** an sqlite `DB`, `PSC2` would **read and write** `DB`. Sometimes `PSC1` would **reload content** from `DB`.

Do you think it is possible?

Do you think two PSC can read / write DB in an atomic way, not not to cause any corruption?

Does PSC put any lock on DB, to precent access from an other PSC?

Comment: Didn't tried that, but I think it could be possible with usage of NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption. Checkout https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Store_Options

Comment: You may be interested in [this approach](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/) which uses 2 `NSManagedObjectContext`s.

Comment: You might want to expand on why you want to do this. The last thing you want is to unnecessarily over-optimize your core data stack. I would love to see what performance you are currently seeing and why you think you need to coordinators to boost that.

Comment: @DanielGalasko it is not optimisation, Core Data is enough fast to fulfil my  expectation, but the origin of the problem is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518146/save-nsundomanager-transactions-one-by-one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have two different `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` instances accessing the same files. In fact, years ago this was a recommended approach.

There are, however, issues with doing so. If one `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` makes a change that is written to the filesystem, the other `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` instance will not be aware of it. `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and `NSManagedObjectContext` maintain in-memory state of the objects they manage. Using two `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` instances will cause them to be out of sync at some point. For example, if `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` A loads an object from records in an `NSPersistentStore` there will be an in-memory version of that object. If `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` B then deletes an object backed by the same records there are no records for A's version of the object. When Core Data attempts to fufil a fault on that object in A you will get an exception.

> Do you think two PSC can read / write DB in an atomic way, not not to cause any corruption?

Corruption is very rarely a problem with NSSQLiteStoreType stores. With other stores it's certainly possible.

> Does PSC put any lock on DB, to precent access from an other PSC?

The built-in `NSPersistentStore` concrete classes us file coordination when accessing the filesystem for records (but not always for metadata). So yes, there is a lock involved, and it should prevent two `NSPersistentStore` instances from modifying the same files at the same time.

As stated above though, that's not the problem you should be concerned about. The in-memory state of the coordinators and their contexts is a much more pressing issue when using multiple coordinators.